# Installing the AMD/ATI Catalyst drivers for 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, radeon

I've tried installing these driver using ever method that I could find. The first way I tried was to just download the drivers from here:

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous/detail?os=Linux%20x86&rev=13.4

I opened the install, selected Generate Distribution Specific Driver Package, select Build package for detected OS: Ubuntu/precise. It runs and then gives and error "Sorry, a problem occurred while installing software. Package: fglrx".

After that failed tried it again but just used the first option which says "Install Driver 13.251 on X.Org 6.9 or later 64-bit. I did that, reboot my computer. After rebooting I had the following message on start up: "The system is running in low-graphics mode". I couldn't get any of the options in the menus to work and I could only use the computer my computer using the terminal. I tried uninstalling the drivers using many guides I found but I could never get it back to the generic drivers. I thought the quickest thing to do would be to format, reinstall and just install the drivers fresh.

After reinstalling the ubuntu, I tried following the following guide:

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-propetary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513)

That didn't work. Got to the "sudo dpkg -i *.deb" command and I get the following error "Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.11.0-18-generic (x86_64)

Then I removed everything and tried this guide:

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Using_Ubuntu-supplied_fglrx.2FCatalyst

This doesn't work either. I get the same error from the above one.

So I've been trying to install this driver all day and can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Using:

- Radeon HD 6850
- Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install fglrx`.

Comment: That just gives me the errror: need a repository as argument.

Comment: Please post the whole output including how did you type command.

Comment: I formatted and reinstalled the OS again. Than I ran this, rebooted, and now it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

This will bring you latest ATI drivers.